# Cannot use Redis as django channels channel layer backend

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to use django_redis's RedisChannelLayer as django channels's channel layer backend. Which results in the websocket opening and closing instantly. But it work fine with In memory channel layer.

channels_redis:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

In Memory Channel Layer:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
class MessageConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel = None
        self.group_name = None

    async def connect(self):
        self.channel = await self.get_channel()
        self.group_name = f"group_{self.channel.id}"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()
```

Comment: Have you verified that the Redis server is up and running on your local machine?

Comment: Yes i did....using redis-cli ping

Comment: I am using redis for celery as well....could that make this happen...or is it something else

Comment: Don't set channel_name to None. let the channel layer name it and even don't change it. it is confusing for the channel layer. just specify the group name